# Plotly table with mini-plot for each row

Tags: python, plotly

Is it possible with Plotly in Python to create a combined table with a mini plot for each row?
Here is an example picture of what I am seeking:

[image]

Explanation:

1. The table show the relevant ticker name along side buy and sell prices and quantities
2. The mini plot is a graphical representation of the buy and sell price with other information (e.g. lowest, highest and current price levels)

I am completely new to Plotly, so I have not made a sample code, as I am not sure whether Plotly has the required functionalities.
I have searched for examples, including in the official Plotly documentation, but I have not been able to find a adequate guide to making such a data representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perfectly doable if this is in HTML but it would require some knowledge of HTML and Jinja templating. If you are unfamiliar with Flask then taking a tutorial in it will teach you a lot. Therefore I will be missing out a lot of necessary how-to here but in order to do so I'd have to teach you HTML and Jinja templating.

Alternatively, look into using Dash since it supports dashboard creation much more easily and does all the heavy lifting for you in terms of HTML. You can easily create tables from your data and charts with sub-charts etc.

Big picture on how you might achieve what you want:

If you can imagine having a table like this.

```
<table>
<th>Ticker</th>
<th>Buy</th>
<th>Sell</th>
<tr>
<td>AAPL
<td>100
<td>150
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SPY
<td>200
<td>5
</tr>
</table>
```

And you wanted to add a line chart to visualise the difference between the buy and the sell, I would add a new table header and then for each new cell (`<td>`) add an embedded chart.

See this resource for embedding charts: https://plotly.com/chart-studio-help/embed-graphs-in-websites/

You can then change the chart sizes to reflect what you need.

Meaning my new table would become:

```
<table>
<th>Ticker</th>
<th>Buy</th>
<th>Sell</th>
<th>Chart</th>
<tr>
<td>AAPL
<td>100
<td>150
<td>/* necessary HTML embed code here */
</tr>
<tr>
<td>SPY
<td>200
<td>5
<td>/* necessary HTML embed code here */
</tr>
</table>
```